# Hide Edit Links in Navigation for users with Contribute permission levels

Tags: permissions

I have users with contribute access level and read access level in my sharepoint 2013 publishing site, users with Read access don't see Edit Links in top Navigation but users with Contribute access see Edit Links. How can I hide Edit links for users with contribute access?

Manage website is already unchecked for contribute access level users. Is there anything else that i am missing in site permissions?

[image]

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code on master page, this would allow only owners to view the edit links:

```
 <Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl runat="server" PermissionsString="FullMask">
    <style>
     .ms-navedit-editLinksText{
      display: none;
     }
     </style>
    </SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>
```

Comment: Where on the master page should I add this code? does it matter?

Comment: hi you can put it on masterpage between:      <head runat="server">  </head>

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using javascript:

```
<Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl runat="server" Permissions="FullMask">
<script type="text/javascript">
     document.getElementById("s4-ribbonrow").style.display = "block";
</script>
</Sharepoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>
```